# sublime text2 in mac forgets all opened files

Tags: macos, sublimetext2, osx-yosemite, text-editor

I have been trying to code in mac using Sublime Text2 but problem is whenever I exit sublime it forgets all the files that I recently opened unlike in Windows this works fine. I have googled some forums and it was mentioned there that

```
 remember_open_files
```

of the default settings must be set to true. I already did that, nothing is working for me. This re-opening of last-recently used files are becoming an inconvenience already. Thanks

Comment: You're supposed to put that inside your User settings file, not the default settings file.

Comment: I did but nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

You must insert that command into the curly braces that you will see in preferences > settings-user > and save.

You should be using Sublime 3 now anyhow.

And lets remember that Mac OS is different from Windows OS we should not expect one to behave exactly like the other.

Good luck